# Pick a contact from the Contacts app; but only list contacts with email

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

I'm trying to select contacts depending on their information, it's working for phone numbers (as far as I can see); but when I try to pick contacts with only email it fails with the following error:

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT typ=vnd.android.cursor.item/email_v2 }
```

Here's my code (or rather the important part):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
if( SMS )
  intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
if( EMAIL )
  intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but not on all devices how it seems. On my HTC Desire S with Android 2.3.5 it works. But same app on a other device (unknown/error report in developer console) it comes to the exact same message you got. You got it fixed? Is there a chance we can come in direct contact to work on this problem together? Here the error message: `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT typ=vnd.android.cursor.item/email_v2 } at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:14...`

Comment: Were you guys able to figure this out? I'm running into the same problem on an older 2.3.7 devices (Droid 1), there simply isn't an email_v2 provided in the system. It works for phone numbers, but not email. Are we stuck checking for this being available and having to provide our own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should be using `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, uri)`, where uri is one of `CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI` or `CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI`. That way, it'll display only contacts with an email or phone.

Comment: I am seeing few email is it weard?

Comment: Probably. Sometimes it will show people that you have emailed only, that don't even exist inside your contacts app. It's a known "issue" I haven't been able to get around.